# what could cause PUSHD to fail?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I've got a great big script that is entirely reliant on PUSHD. However suddenly when I type `pushd \\server1\dir1` I'm getting:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\userNameHere>pushd \\server1\dir1
' '
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

OK, I'm aware that CMD doesn't support UNC paths. That's why I'm using PUSHD. When I search for this I find lots of posts that say "When you encounter this message about UNC paths, you should use PUSHD!". Well crap, I'm encountering that message *and* using PUSHD.

I tried using `CMD /E:ON` because PUSHD is only active when Command Extensions are enabled, apparently. Same result.

I looked to see if somehow I was out of drive letters (since PUSHD starts at Z: and goes backward to find a drive letter). Nope.

I tried starting my cmd at the c:\ dir (`cd c:\` then `pushd \\server1\dir1`).

I confirmed that the drive is there and I have access to it, via Windows Explorer.

And now I'm out of ideas.

Pushd reference: [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pushd.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK the answer to this, as far as I can tell, is that if you're at Y: in your mapped drives then pushd won't work. So you need to do `net use y: /delete` (or some other drive letter) then map your drive using `pushd`. I had all drive letters mapped, except for Z and A. Maybe Z is reserved? I dunno.

My mistake was checking to see if Z: was available (it wasn't mapped). Apparently if you've mapped everything up to and including Y: then it won't map Z:. No idea why.

Comment: You can also right click on the mapped drive in My Computer and click 'Disconnect'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure command extensions are enabled.

The registry keys are:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions
and/or
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions
```

Set to either `0x1` (Enabled) or `0x0` (Disabled). The user specific setting takes precedence over the machine setting.

Also make sure that there are drive letters available for the `pushd` command. If all drive letters are already mapped and in use then the `pushd` command will fail in the same way you have detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Would not mapping the drive to the letter as usual would do the trick prior to 'pushd'...as in your example

```
net use E: \\\\server1\\dir1
pushd E:\
....
popd
```

Comment: pushd isn't supposed to be dependent on net use. The point of pushd is to 'just figure it out': map a drive and change the pwd over to it.