# pushd not allowing UNC paths, cmd extensions are enabled

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, unc

I've used the [`pushd "%~dp0"` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020832/14420) for years to run batch files from server locations without issue. It's not working anymore, and it's not because CMD extensions are unavailable or I've run out of drive letters ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437293/14420),[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411626/14420)).  Any clue what's going on?

System is Win7-Pro SP1 x64.

3rd party installs which interact with or modify CMD (I'm pretty sure I've used pushd+UNC after installing these, it's a very common technique, but can't swear to it):

- [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) 160619 (x64) Stable
- [Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) v0.4.4

.

```
d:\>pushd \\server4\share
' '
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

.

```
d:\>reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v EnableExtensions

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1

d:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           B:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           F:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           G:        \\server2\corp             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           H:        \\server3\home             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           I:        \\server4\share            Microsoft Windows Network
OK           N:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           O:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           P:        \\server5\files            Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Q:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           R:        \\server5\work             Microsoft Windows Network
             S:        \\server6\data             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           T:        \\server5\maps             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           U:        \\server7\layers           Microsoft Windows Network
OK           V:        \\server8\home\me          Microsoft Windows Network
OK           W:        \\server5\warehouse        Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\server5\work             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Y:        \\server5\dev_repo         Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Z:        \\server5\repository       Microsoft Windows Network
OK                     \\server5\work             Microsoft Windows Network
                       \\mysites.sharepoint.org\DavWWWRoot  Web Client Network
OK                     \\server4\ITSupport        Microsoft Windows Network
                       \\sharepoint.org@SSL\DavWWWRoot  Web Client Network
                       \\sharepoint.org\DavWWWRoot      Web Client Network

The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Not a solution, but: in case `pushd` fails, I do the following: `pushd \\server4\share || exit /B 1`, so there is no `popd` executed which could lose a path from another `pushd`...

Comment: Why not just use the UNC path directly in your batch file.  I am hoping some day MS will get rid of drive letters and just use mount points.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I *was* out of drive letters, but not from mapped or local drives. I have a Dell display with integrated USB hub, and it pre-allocates drive letters J: to L: even if no device is plugged in. I use them so rarely I'd forgotten all about that.

What led me to the discovery was deleting all non-essential mapped drives and repeatedly `pushd \\server\share` until the error occurred, noticing it always jumped some drive letters, and then having a look at Disk Management.

```
D:\>pushd \\server\share

Q:\>pushd \\server\share

O:\>pushd \\server\share

N:\>pushd \\server\share

F:\>pushd \\server\share

B:\>pushd \\server\share
' '
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

[image: Disk Management showing pre-allocated USB drive letters]

Comment: Unfortunately, `net use` does not support characters other than letters as drive _letters_ (opposed to `subst`, which allows almost every character)...

Comment: Whoa @aschipfl that is cool. I didn't know subst could use non-letter characters. (A hint of the [Amiga `assign`](http://wiki.amigaos.net/wiki/AmigaOS_Manual:_AmigaDOS_Command_Reference#ASSIGN) which could be any length of characters. I miss it every day.) Thank you!

Comment: `subst` even seems to work together with UNC paths (unexpectedly); anyway, do you really need all the drives simultaneously? what about using a loop that maps one or some drives and destroys it/then when the iteration is done? To securely find a free drive letter you could use `pushd "\\%ComputerName%\ADMIN$"` and capture its output by `for /F`, for example...

Comment: ...Uhm, `pushd` does not produce any output to capture, but there are ways to get the current drive; for instance, to read variable `%CD%` and split off the drive part...

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html - reference doc that includes this undocumented behaviour plus caution re: not all defined drives are listed after the fact (up to you to remember they were created). Plus severe performance warning on unavailable network resources. @aschipfl

Answer (score 1):

I can see some multiple temporary drive mappings of the same UNC path in `net use` output, for instance `\\server1\dev`:

```
OK           B:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           F:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           N:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           O:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Q:        \\server1\dev              Microsoft Windows Network
```

Note that `popd` is used along with `pushd` in the linked [pushd "%~dp0" trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020832/14420):

```
@echo off

    :: Create a temporary drive letter mapped to your UNC root location
    ::                          and effectively CD to that location
pushd "%~dp0"

    :: Do your work
       :: launch executables directly
something.exe parameters
       :: aternatively, launch executables using START
start "" something.exe parameters

       :: IMPORTANT! launch batch files using CALL command
       ::            to return from a called script to the calling one
CALL something.BAT parameters
CALL something.CMD parameters

    :: Remove the temporary drive letter and return to your original location
POPD
```

Comment: Yeah popd is important to release the drive letter. I was troubleshooting a script which was exiting prematurely and never getting to popd. Looking at net use output I thought I still had 4 or more letters to go and was postponing cleanup until I "had to". (Grandma always did say lazy hands work twice...)